# cmake - find path to ignore a directory

Tags: cmake

How do I make cmake ignore a directory when doing find_path? I'm trying to find the system's freetype2 library, but instead it is finding the one that inside my project. How do I get it to ignore that?

Here's what my FindFreeTypeTwo.cmake looks like

```
FIND_PATH(_FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR ft2build.h PATH_SUFFIXES freetype2)
FIND_LIBRARY(_FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES NAMES freetype)

INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(Freetype2 DEFAULT_MSG _FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES _FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR)

if (FREETYPE2_FOUND)
   set (FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR ${_FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR})
   set (FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES ${_FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES})
endif (FREETYPE2_FOUND)
```

This is what my file structure looks like.

```
  \ 
   \ src
    | CMakeLists.tst
     \ build
      \ cmake_config
       \ find_packages
        | FindFreeTypeTwo.cmake
   \ (folder to exclude)
   \ (other folders)
```

Comment: There's a well-tested FindFreetype.cmake find-module which ships with CMake. Did you try it?

Comment: Regarding your actual question, the [find_path](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_path.html) docs should answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the parameters in the `FIND_PATH()`. Instead of using the `PATH_SUFFIXES`, you could use something like this 
`FIND_PATH(_FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR ft2build.h HINTS ENV FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIR PATHS /usr/local/include)`
This is something I usually use when I write cmake file.